# Website gets pushed when hovered over input. No input:hover coded

Tags: html, css, input

I made a simple search bar. The problem is that my whole site seems to be pushed a few pixels down when I hover over the input. I had a `.search2:hover`, but I removed it and the pushing is still occurring. Does anyone have a clue why?

```css
.search2{
 position: absolute;
 top:5%;
 left: 40%;
 width: 600px;
 height: 40px;
 font-size:11pt;
 border-radius: 40px;
 border-width: thin;
 border-color:#e6e6e6;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 background: #fff;
 border-style:solid;
 text-indent: 20px;
}
```

```html
<form action="search.php" method="get">
   <input type="text" name="q" class="search2" autocomplete="off">
   
</form>
```

Comment: Have you used the browser's inspector to see where the style is coming from? Chrome and others will allow you to force a state such as hover, active, or focus on a particular element.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The issue you are describing is not present in the sample code you have provided.

Comment: As @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas explains, use Google Chrome (etc) inspector tools to force hover. You can also then view the "Computed" tab to manually go back and forth and see any changes.

Comment: I tested a little bit more, also with the force hover/focus tool, but it doesn't seem like it has to do with the state. I'm looking a bit more into it and if I find the source of the problem I will come back.

Comment: It behaves a little different every time. Now it just pushes every time when I change any state(hover/active/focus). I hover over a link on the page to reset it to normal position. If I go in inspect-element-mode it completely goes crazy. some things just bug half way over the screen if I hover over the input box with inspect elements on. I don't know what is happening.

Comment: @murmelgrumpf you need to add more code in order to display the issue. If there is not enough room in the snippet tool, look at jsfiddle.net. I would suggest removing browser-added margin/padding **at the top of your css** for a start (*{margin:0px; padding:0px;}) - note the asterisk. Also minimise use of absolute positioning and if use relative (pos)  and display:inline-block for links. Best of luck

Comment: I don't know what browser you are using, but in my Chrome nothing to the effect of what you describe happens. Do you maybe have some browser add-ons that are causing this effect?

Comment: Oh damn, a browser made occurrence. That's disappointing. I gues I just have to live with it. Btw, I'm using edge. My computer is literally to bad for chrome... But thanks anyway guys.